# Angular model not updating

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

Hi I am trying to update the model based on the value of the radio buttons. I read that it might be something with $parent scope but I am unable to figure it out. I am fairly new to angular and still trying to understand scope. Any help is appreciated.

Code: I am tying the value of the radio buttons to the ng-model="amount" but they wont update at all. Here is my jsbin with my code. http://jsbin.com/zumuc/8/edit Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here we go: http://jsbin.com/lasesabu/1
http://jsbin.com/lasesabu/1/edit

Just using data.amount in place of amount. The difference is changing object content versus replacing object.